# aci_gatt_add_serv() returns out of memory

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, stm32, bluenrg

Can you increase/allocate more memory to a service? How do I do this?

The first 3 services I add have no issues. When I add the fourth service I have a ret of 0x1f(out of memory).

My service lookes like:

```
tBleStatus add_last10_fault_group_service(void){

    tBleStatus ret;
    Custom_Service_UUID_t last10_faults_service_uuid;
    Custom_Char_UUID_t last10_faults_char1_uuid,last10_faults_char2_uuid,last10_faults_char3_uuid;


    //copy uuid
    BLUENRG_memcpy(&last10_faults_service_uuid.Service_UUID_128,LAST10_FAULT_SERVICE_UUID,16);

    /*Add service*/
    ret = aci_gatt_add_serv(UUID_TYPE_128, last10_faults_service_uuid.Service_UUID_128, PRIMARY_SERVICE, 16, &last10_faults_service_handle);

    BLUENRG_memcpy(&last10_faults_char1_uuid.Char_UUID_128,LAST10_FAULT_CHAR1_UUID,16);
    BLUENRG_memcpy(&last10_faults_char2_uuid.Char_UUID_128,LAST10_FAULT_CHAR2_UUID,16);
    BLUENRG_memcpy(&last10_faults_char3_uuid.Char_UUID_128,LAST10_FAULT_CHAR3_UUID,16);


      

    return ret;
}
```